# Help deciphering a Kurrent letter

Tags: letter, handwriting, kurrent

My abilities in neither German nor Kurrent are very advanced, and i need some help trying to decipher a letter from 1758. I checked on the Wikimedia Commons page for the image of this letter, but sadly found no information about its contents there—let alone a full transcription. I'm interested in this because seeing a transcription should help me to better my Kurrent-reading skills, and also i'm curious for an example of some earlier modern German.
I've tried my hand at identifying some of the words, but haven't really got that far!
The image is attached and any native help would be much appreciated.

[image: Letter from Lessing]

(From https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lessing_Kleist-Brief.jpg)

Edit after answer: I accidentally used the wrong /das/ in one of my notes. On the topic of missing eszetts, i thought one of those big long words said 'Geheimnis', but the double s threw me off, and so i assumed the first letter to be a B, despite its similarity to how i write my Gs, and abandoned trying to work it out. Nice to see this did indeed bring to light some differences to note.

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: Whoops- i'd inserted it dodgily

Comment: Can you please cite the source of the letter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transcribed in Latin script it is here:

https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Gotthold_Ephraim_Lessing_an_Ewald_von_Kleist

> Liebster Freund,
>
> Morgen geht das Bataillon Garde von hier weg; nach Breßlau, wie man
>   sagt das ist die einzige Neuigkeit, die ich Ihnen von hier melden
>   kann. Oder wollen Sie noch etwas neues von Gottscheden[1] wißen? Er
>   wird mit den Gesalbten unsres Gleims[2] immer bekannter; immer
>   vertrauter. Er hat wieder französische Verse gesetzt, nebst einer
>   goldnen Tabatiere[3] und einem Ringe. Er macht gar kein Geheimniß
>   draus; er ist vielmehr so stolz drauf, daß er die ganze Unterredung,
>   die er hier mit dem Könige gehabt hat, in sein Neu[e]stes eindrucken
>   laßen. Gott wolle nicht, daß unser Gleim seinen Patriotismum auch so
>   weit treibt, daß ihm Gottsched durch diese Bekanntschaft respectabler
>   wird! Jetzt ist es vielmehr die rechte Zeit, neue und blutigere
>   Satyr[e]n wider ihn zu machen, als man noch je gemacht hat. Und wenn
>   wir damit zaudern, so wird er uns selbst zuvorkommen. Denn es ist ganz
>   gewiß, daß er wieder eine neue Aesthetik in einer Nuß drucken läßt.
>   Ihre neuen Gedichte werden ihm gleich noch zur rechten Zeit gekommen
>   seyn. Wenn ich doch nur auch unterdeßen etwas geschrieben hätte, damit
>   ich nicht etwa vergeßen würde!
>
> Leben Sie wohl theuerster, liebster Freund und kommen Sie ja bald
>   wieder. Ich bin Zeit Lebens
>
> ganz der ihrige Leßing
>
> Leipzig den 14 März 1758

Comment: Oh it was there all along—thank you!